# How to get numbers 1-20 into an array, then separate even and odd numbers and print them on the web browser

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Im new to Javascript and i cant figure out how to make this work. I have to use an array. I can only get it to show one of the numbers in the browser.

it prints:

Even Number = 20

I need it to print:

Odd Number = 1 
Even Number = 2
Odd Number = 3
Even Number = 4
Odd Number = 5
Even Number = 6
Odd Number = 7
Even Number = 8
Odd Number = 9
Even Number = 10
Odd Number = 11
Even Number = 12
Odd Number = 13
Even Number = 14
Odd Number = 15
Even Number = 16
Odd Number = 17
Even Number = 18
Odd Number = 19
Even Number = 20

Here is what I have. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <script>
 var numbers = [];

 for (var i=1; i<=20; i++){
    numbers.push(i);

    if (i % 2 === 0){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Even Number = "+i;


    }

    else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Odd Number = "+i;    
    }

  }

  </script>
```

Comment: `.innerHTML = ...` overwrites the complete content of the element. You want `+=` instead of `=`.

Comment: Every time you use `innerHTML`, you're ___replacing___ the existing contents of that element.

Comment: There's also no need to use an array. It's pretty much pointless in your code.

Comment: @Andy its probably a requirement for the OP's homework

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you are doing `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` it is overwriting the previous content. Instead during each iteration create a `div` element and then append that as child of `div#demo`

```js
var numbers = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  numbers.push(i);
  let createElem = document.createElement('div');
  let creatTxtNode;
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    createTxtNode = document.createTextNode("Even Number = " + i);
  } else {
    createTxtNode = document.createTextNode("Odd Number = " + i);
  }
  createElem.appendChild(createTxtNode)
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(createElem);
}
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assigning (`=`) the new value to the element, in each iteration the previous values are removed. You can either use `+=` to concatenate the new value with the previous value **OR** try with [**`insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
var numbers = [];
var targetEl = document.getElementById("demo")
for (var i=1; i<=20; i++){
  numbers.push(i);
  if (i % 2 === 0){
    targetEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Even Number = "+i + "<br>");
  }
  else {
    targetEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Odd Number = "+i+ "<br>");   
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path with your solution. Just replace `innerHTML = ...` with `innerHTML += ...`.

That will do the trick for you since with each iteration innerHTML operation is replacing your existing content, you actually need to append it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
var copyNumbers = [];
var targetEl = document.getElementById("getNumbers")
numbers.forEach(function(i) {
  copyNumbers.push(i);
  switch (i % 2) {
    case 0:
      getNumbers.innerHTML += ("Even Number = <b><i>" + i + "</i></b><br />");
      break;
    default:
      getNumbers.innerHTML += ("Odd Number = <b><i>" + i + "</i></b><br />");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='getNumbers'></div>
```

Note:- you need to replace `innerHTML =` ... with `innerHTML +=` .... each iteration instead of replacing your existing content, you need to append it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </body>
   <script>
          function evenOdd() {
             //Create an array of even odd numbers result
             evenOddArray = [...Array(20).keys()].map(x => {
                  if((x+1)%2==0){
                       return "Even Number = " + (x+1)
                   }
                   return "Odd Number = " + (x+1)
             })

             //loop through each result
             evenOddArray.forEach(x => {
               var t = document.createTextNode(x);// Create a text node
               var br = document.createElement("br") // Create a new line node
               document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(t) //append to demo
               document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(br)
            })
          }
          evenOdd()

      </script>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zpcu5mb8/

Answer (score 0):

There are two key things.

First, as the others have noted, your use of `innerHTML` simply replaces the content each time which is why you're only getting the last output from the loop.

Second: *"I have to use an array."*

While you're pushing numbers to your array in your example ultimately it's pointless - you add numbers to it but don't *use* the array in any way. If it's a requirement for your work, you might get marked down for that.

So here's an example that fixes both issues:

1) It creates an array of numbers

2) It loops over that array of numbers and produces the output

```js
// First we create out numbers array...
const numbers = [];

// ...and fill it with numbers
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  numbers.push(i);
}

// We create an output array to store our strings
// You could concatenate the strings in the loop with `+=`
// but building an array and joining it up later is a little cleaner
const output = [];

// Now: loop over the numbers array
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

  // Grab the number. We want to check whether that 
  // is even/odd instead of the index
  const number = numbers[i];

  // Our condition: we push a different string to the array
  // depending on whether its even/odd. I've used template literals
  // as they're cleaner solution to using string concatenation
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    output.push(`Even number = ${number}`);
  } else {
    output.push(`Odd number = ${number}`);
  }
}

// Finally we grab our element
const demo = document.querySelector('#demo');

// And we add the joined up array to it
demo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', output.join('<br/>'));
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

#### Further reading

- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)